# How to turn off colors in ZSH shell? Make it black and white with unicode support!

Tags: shell, terminal, colors, freebsd, zsh

Once when I got my hand on openbsd I was really happy to have black and white terminal, I, somehow, orienting much more with b/w colors..

Anyway I know just one option to do it.

```
export TERM="linux-m"
```

and openbsd used something else like "vt8.." i don't remember.

Now I have freebsd on my dedicated server, I want to have black and white terminal again. On bash it works perfectly even in sh, i got normal unicode in Midnight commander for example... but when I entering ZSH with TERM="linux-m" in mc I have unicode problem , edges just a bunch of letters...

in /etc/login.conf i've got this locales:

```
unicode|Unicode Users Accounts:\
        :charset=UTF-8:\
        :lang=en_US.UTF-8:\
        :lc_all=en_US.UTF-8:\
        :tc=default:
```

here's screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I misunderstand something please correct me. I just want to have nice edges everywhere in zsh... with black and white colors.

Comment: note: on osx bash it's TERM=linux-m =)

Comment: whats the name of app of the first screenshot?

Comment: @mkultra: The OP mentions it: Midnight Commander.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
TERM=xterm-mono
```

Comment: @WayneAshleyBerry: The OP mentions in a comment that it's `TERM=linux-m`.